# Certification authority not working after installation : gives error - system cannot find the file specified. 0x80070002

Tags: certificate-authority, windows-server-2019

I've a Windows Server 2019 Standard edition machine. I've installed below server roles using Server Manager:

- Active Directory Certificate Services (**AD CS**)
- Certificate Authority (**CA**)

Now, when I try to start **Certification Authority** console from **Server Manager** or try **certsrv.msc** from **Run** prompt then it gives below error:

> --------------------------- Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services
> --------------------------- The system cannot find the file specified. 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
>
> ---

I also tried running the **certsrv.msc** from start menu via **Run as administrator** option but still no change in error (Refer screenshot):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get an answer from [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0b36474-2daf-421f-9345-42e672922dd7/installing-certification-authority-on-server-2012-datacenter-rtm-results-in-0x80070002-and-certsrv?forum=winserver8gen) thread on Microsoft TechNet. The issue turned out to be with the configuration of Certification Authority (CA). Post installation, some additional configuration steps have to be completed before we can start using the CA. For this step, you will see a pending action notification in **Server Manager** (Refer screenshot).

[image]

When we click on **Configure Active Directory Certificate Services on th...** link then a wizard opens up which helps configuring the CA. Here are the important wizard steps for your ready reference:

[image]

Press <kbd>Next</kbd> to go to the next wizard step (Refer screenshot):

[image]

Press <kbd>Next</kbd> to go to the next wizard step (Refer screenshot):

[image]

Press <kbd>Next</kbd> to go to the next wizard step (Refer screenshot):

[image]

Press <kbd>Next</kbd> to go to the next wizard step (Refer screenshot):

[image]

Press <kbd>Next</kbd> to go to the next wizard step (Refer screenshot):

[image]

Press <kbd>Configure</kbd> to finish the wizard. This will complete the CA configuration process and the issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but my error was 0x8007001c . Providing solution for future googlers:

Apparently the issue was that incorrect settings were migrated while upgrading the CA. Fixed by IIS managment console > Sites, Default, Certserv > Handler Mappings > right click, Revert to parent.